# Counting the observations through each path of a data.tree in R

Tags: r, tree

Using data.tree to build a custom hierarchy, I'm looking to count the number of observations that run through each node.

```
library(MASS)
library(data.tree)

data(Cars93)

Cars93 <- subset(Cars93, Manufacturer %in% c("Acura","Toyota"))[, c("Manufacturer","DriveTrain","Passengers")]

> Cars93
       Manufacturer DriveTrain Passengers
1         Acura      Front          5
2         Acura      Front          5
84       Toyota      Front          5
85       Toyota      Front          4
86       Toyota      Front          5
87       Toyota        4WD          7
```

The current output is adding children correctly for the first sub node, but then skips the "DriveTrain" column for the "Acura" level, and the "Toyota" level stopped adding "Passengers" children after the first iteration.

```
  levelName       Obs.Ct
1 Cars               6
2  ¦--Acura          2
3  ¦   °--5          2
4  °--Toyota         4
5      ¦--4WD        1
6      ¦   °--7      1
7      °--Front      3
```

All of the built-in counting functions appear to only apply to the node and leaf levels, not the observation levels, so hopefully I'm not missing something there.  Building the tree from a data frame one node at a time and counting the rows is the only solution I've come across.

I've come close updating the Training code from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/applications.html#id3-introduction, however it breaks somewhere between splitting on each feature and recursively calling the function for each child.  I've also tried sapply'ing the split to all of the features at once, which just results adding children to the wrong levels of the hierarchy.  This is the closest I've been able to align the output.

```
IsPure <- function(data) {
    length(unique(data[, ncol(data)])) == 1
}

path_func <- function(node, data) {
    node$Obs.Ct <- nrow(data)

    if (IsPure(data)) {
        child <- node$AddChild(unique(data[, ncol(data)]))
        child$Obs.Ct <- nrow(data)

    } else {
        childObs <- split(data[ , 2:ncol(data), drop = FALSE], data[ , 1], drop = TRUE)

        for(i in 1:length(childObs)) {
            child <- node$AddChild(names(childObs)[i])
            path_func(child, childObs[[i]])
        }
    }
}

tree <- Node$new("Cars")
path_func(tree, Cars93)
print(tree, "Obs.Ct")
```